# Unsuccessful: create table using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I get this error when I want to create a new table in hibernate

```
SEVERE: Unsuccessful: create table gmail.messages.test (CODE_PERS varchar(255) not null, LAST_NAME varchar(255), FIRST_NAME varchar(255), primary key (CODE_PERS))
3.8.2012 18:30: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport create
SEVERE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.test (CODE_PERS varchar(255) not null, LAST_NAME varchar(255), FIRST_NAME varch' at line 1
3.8.2012 18:30: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
```

here is my hibernate.cfg file

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmail.messages</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
<!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="auto"/> -->

<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="transaction.factory_class">
    org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
</property>
<property name="use_outer_join">false</property>
<property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">12</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">gmail.messages</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<mapping resource="HibernateMapping/hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
```

Comment: Are we allowed to use .(dot) symbol in table name?

Comment: I tried with org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect                         and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto="auto"/update but still the same error

Comment: I would suggest just try with simple table name, something like message_test instead of gmail.mes.....

Comment: could you please post the full "create table" query?

Comment: yeah,that was the problem no dots are allowed to use. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As shown by the stack trace, Hibernate caught an exception from the MySQL database, so try executing the query directly in the database ( it's much easier to debug direct than through framework).

Your query will execute successfully if you change the dot in the table name to an underscore.

Comment: I created new database without dot between worlds with same properties  and it works.  Thanks